# Fancytree nodes removed but UI not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, fancytree

I have a strange issue with FancyTree while doing lazy load the previous items are not getting cleared.

```
 lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
 data.node.removeChildren();
                    data.result = {
                        url: request_url + "?type=get"
                        };
}
```

The previous children are still there and new data is appending, however, in node.children method, I don't see them.
Looks like the issue is with UI reload but not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy nodes should not have children, just the `lazy` attribute set.

Only when the node is expanded for the first time, the `lazyLoad()` callback gets called. Therefore there is no need to remove children.